# Como pegar uma parte de um nome de arquivo em shell script?

Tags: shell-script

Eu tenho um arquivo que tem o formato `nome1-nome2-0.0.0.0.war`, e através do *shell* queria pegar a versão (0.0.0.0) e guardá-la numa variável para depois usá-la para criar um diretório.

**Obs.:** As versões mudam, mas os nomes e a extensão são as mesmas. Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer de algumas formas, uma delas é:

```
ls nome1-nome2-0.0.0.0.war| egrep  -wo '[\.0-9]+'
```

O output disso será: **0.0.0.0**

Explicação:

Eu criei um arquivo chamado *nome1-nome2-0.0.0.0.war*, executei um `grep` utilizando a seguinte regex `'[\.0-9]+'`, o parâmetro `o` e `w`, foram necessários para dar match em somente o que a regex contemplava.

Um script que vá varrer uma pasta e criar outras pastas baseadas na versões do seu app, poderia ser:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls *.war|egrep  -wo '[\.0-9]+')
do
    mkdir $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.war | awk -F '-' {'print $3'} | awk -F '.war' {'print $1'}
while read versao
do
    mkdir $versao 
done
```

Comment: Esta resposta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo. Por favor, se possível e se esta for uma solução ao problema, explique melhor como você o resolveu. O código pode ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários pode não ser.